# If 2 penalties are called on the same play, and a goal is scored in the following 3v5; who comes out of the box?

Tags: ice-hockey

If 2 penalties are called on the same play. 2 minors, 2 minutes each, and so they are put on the board at the same moment.

If a goal is scored on the following 3v5 powerplay, one of those penalties has to be waved. But is there any logic on which of the 2 players gets out?

Usual logic would be that the one with the least time remaining gets out, but since we've got 2 players with the same time remaining, how is it decided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The captain decides.

This decision is made at the time that the penalties are assessed, which of multiple skaters will be first (second, third, ...) to leave the box, whether it is due to the expiration of the penalties or a goal being scored during the concurrent  minor penalties.

This decision is passed by the referee to the scorekeepers, who will "line up" the players accordingly - both in their notes for later reference and physically for moving them back onto the ice.

See for example, IIHF Rulebook 111, *Penalty Situations*, part v.